Why does dart/flutter sometimes require comma instead of semicolon in dart?
I have a unique situation where flutter/dart seems to be requiring a coma for line endings instead of semi colon and I am completely baffled. Is this correct behavior or is there some major bug going on?
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => {
    prefs.setString("auth", sr.data);
    prefs.setString("phone", myPhone);
}

produces the error "Expected to find '}'
if I change them to commas its totall fine
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => {
    prefs.setString("auth", sr.data),
    prefs.setString("phone", myPhone),
}

I have a lot more code in here with if statements and other things going on but its all the same. Any semicolon produces the error and commas seem to make everything happy. If this is correct behavior how do I know when commas are needed??

Don't know flutter, but maybe Object Notation (like Json) vs separate sentances?

maybe I have plenty of other inline functions like this that use semicolons fine. It just seems to be true with the .then on getInstance. Basically it seems like this particular function has unique syntax. Honestly dart is the ugliest language i know out of the 12 I can code in

This question is similar to: Why can't I declare this local variable in dart?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In short: when you do () => { expr1, expr2 }, you're returning a set. What you want is either () => expr or () { expr1; expr2; }. Dart is not like JS in this case.

@DhafinRayhan I don't understand that question enough to say. But someone gave a perfect answer below

@noone392 see my answer or that question. It will answer your confusion about the () => { expr } syntax in Dart.

() {} requires semi column
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    prefs.setString("auth", sr.data);
    prefs.setString("phone", myPhone);
}

() => {} requires comma
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => {
    prefs.setString("auth", sr.data),
    prefs.setString("phone", myPhone),
}


Don't ever do second. You are returning a set for absolute no reason. This is not JS. @noone392 , this answer is misleading.

@DhafinRayhan thanks for additional information. I didn't realize I accidentally did a lambda i think some mental syntax from other languages like c# snuck in lol

I didn't tell him to use more a solution than an other I just gave him a response and I think he got it

The solution doesn't actually give the answer, and @noone392 in its comment does not know what he's talking about.
() {} is a function, whose code exists inside of {}.
() => {} is also a function, but one that return an empty Map object.
This is the code that OP wants (notice the lack of =>):
SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    prefs.setString("auth", sr.data);
    prefs.setString("phone", myPhone);
}


An empty set of braces ({}) by default will be an empty Map, but in the OP's example the braces are not empty and will attempt to return a Set literal.  This answer also would be better if it additionally answered the question about commas vs. semicolons: Set literals must contain comma-separated elements, not semicolon-terminated statements.

Yeah this did not answer my question at all. The question was about comma vs semi colons. This is clearly a statement intended for those who already know the answer.

@noone392 It's clearly better than the accepted answer. That one pretended to be the "answer", but does not give the real reason on why the comma vs semicolon thing makes difference. It only misleads people who have no idea much further.
